# How to configure my backup windows 2003 server to authenticate people when main DC goes down?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller

I wish to designate a second server to authenticate people on the domain when the main server is down for repair, maintainace, updates installation etc. At the moment, the second it goes to reboot, no one can log in, and I have to wait till after hours.

I know this is a gap in my knowledge, and I want to fix this once and for all!

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is run dcpromo on your second server to add it to the domain. That will make it a second DC, and it will be able to authenticate your users.

That's the simple answer. You should read up on AD because there may be important details that you could miss. If your current DC is a DNS server, the second one should also be a DNS server. Unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise, they should be AD-integrated DNS.

Comment: +1. Though it's not specifically mentioned, it's worth noting that there is no "backup" DC, they are all equal (except for the FSMO roles). In NT4 there was a primary and backups; that is not the case with Active Directory.

Comment: On the second server that I wish to use as the 'backup domain controller' (Thank you for the clarification of terminology :)) it is currently running DNS for the domain.

From the comments, I should run DCPROMO on the 'BDC' and install DNS on second server, (My DNS is AD integrated already).

This should mean that so long as one of the two servers is up, the domain will run as expected with no downtime?

Comment: Pretty much. It depends on the amount of downtime. If the first DC is also your only DHCP server, then any machines who's lease expires will probably drop off the network (this behavior may be definable though.) Like I said, there's a lot of reading that you can and should do on AD. Also - like @Chris said, there is no BDC, you'll get a lot of flack for using a term that is no longer operative. There are only DCs.

Comment: +1 I would add that the second server should also be made a Global Catalog server.  I generally make all of my DCs GCs

Comment: @gWaldo - that's a useful detail, and a very good idea in an Exchange environment. If you're in one or a small handful of well-connected sites, with a single domain, there's not much reason to *not* make them all GCs. Like I told the OP, he should do a lot of reading.

Comment: @mfinni I tend to make them all GC's because there is so little overhead to doing so, and the sanity that comes from knowing that - load issues aside - that a single surviving DC can run the entire environment for short periods of time.  But if you don't trust your replication or networking, well, you already know that you have issues...

Comment: @gWaldo - If you have a complex environment with multiple domains, the overhead of a GC can become *quite* significant ;-) But I agree on making them all GCs in a single domain environment.

Comment: Single Domain over here! *rubs hands* Okay, so I guess making all my servers GC will be fun - And I'm going to through in an extra DHCP server, why not?! I thank you guys for your input, feel free to ask me more questions, and throw more ideas my way :)

Comment: @massimo that is a good point.

Comment: The only other point that I'd have to make is to put your PDC Emulator role on your beefiest DC because it's going to get most of the load.

Comment: @Guru - watch out with a second DHCP server in a single subnet. It's easily done, but you don't want the ranges to overlap. If you design it wrong, you could have some inconveniences.

Comment: I didn't realise that was how this works! *so very sorry!* I have to go back through all my answers now!